# How to overload operator -= C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need to overload the assignment/decrement operator (-=) so that the code

```
object -= int
```

decrements `object.life` class member by the value on the rhs. Here is my code:

```
const Object& Object::operator -= (const Object& obj)
{ 
    if (life == obj.life)`
    {   
        this->life -= obj.life;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

How do I implement this in my main?

```
int main()
{ 
    Object o1;
    o1 -= 5; //DOESN'T WORK
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: it's because int cannot be converted to an Object, simply add a second operator to handle ints

Comment: @emartel You could post that as an answer.

Comment: @Corbin no need, a ton of people already posted the same answers :)

Comment: I would advice against this design. While today it might look like a good idea to overload `operator-=` to mean decrement life, in the future you or other developers will find `a -= 10` where `a` is of type `Object` and will be puzzled trying to understand what it means to substract an integer from an object. I'd recommend that yo implement a regular member function: `void Object::reduceLife(int)` which is self documenting.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: if the `life` variables are not equal, your function doesn't return anything, which is wrong.  Also, you should probably return a mutable reference, not a `cosnt` reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overloading the case when you subtract an object from an object, but the example you show is subtracting an integer. I you want to overload the operator that takes an integer:

```
const Object& Object::operator-= (int x);
```

Comment: Ok, so how would i implement this in my driver? Let's say i wanted to decrease by 5; w1 -= 5 would work?

Answer (score 3):

The overload should take `int`, not `Object`:

```
Object& Object::operator -= (int amount);
```

Or, alternatively, **if it makes sense**, you could write a constructor that takes an `int` to allow *implicit* conversion from `int` to `Object` type. The argument should be used to initialize `life`.

Comment: A non-explicit constructor taking an `int` could come back to haunt you. I think the overload is safer.

Comment: Creating a constructor that takes an `int` can be VERY misleading! This will create a temporary `Object` without anyone noticing. It's a case where an `explicit` constructor is necessary and an operator for `int` is better in my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try using this:-

```
const Object& Object::operator-= (int x)
```

since overload should take `int`